# How to use WebSphere 8.5 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, websphere

I am not familiar with the IBM product. I am currently use Tomcat as the server for my localhost. Now I would like to test in WebSphere 8.5. But in Eclipse, I could only choose Tomcat as my server. I would like to ask how to install and test in WebSphere 8.5. My eclipse version is indigo.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install WebSphere Developer Tools in Eclipse via Marketplace (search for WebSphere developer tools indigo).

Then you will need to get runtime, if you dont have it:

- for full version [download](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasdevelopers/) WebSphere Application Server v8.5.5.x for Developers (which is free),
- or you can use [WebSphere Liberty Profile](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-eclipse/) (a new lightweight version that supports Java EE 7, but doesn't contain some old WebSphere programming extensions).

Comment: You is DEV và not System. If DEV you can select orther eclipse. Also you is System should choice eclipse and run command for scripts and run all function from WebSphere Application Console. Simple than Eclipse please

Comment: @Kotler Unfortunately I dont understand your comment. Maybe try to use google translator or reformat it in more readable version.

Comment: you want user DEV as develop not system adminitrator. As system adminitrator not user eclipse. Need known correctly you is DEV not System for support please

Comment: @Kotler The Eclipes is Dev tool. Question was about Eclipse. If you have different problem/issue create NEW question and describe your problem there.